# Created a UYVY image over directshow and its corrupted and im not sure why

Tags: c#, directshow, directshow.net

I have a buffer of UYVY data from a camera and i am using the GSSF Directshow.net filter to push the buffer through a graph.

The Graph at the moment is

```
GSSF -> YUV Transform -> AVI Splitter -> Video Renderer
```

The graph correctly calculates the color and is displaying it correctly but theres bars in the image that shouldn't be there and i am not sure where they are coming from. It hurts my eyes to stare at the image.

[image]

This function takes the UYVY buffer (mainbyte) and copies it to an array of integers

```
        unsafe public void ImageFromPixels__()
    {
        byte[] x = mainbyte;
        long fff = 720 * 1280;
        mainptr = new IntPtr(fff);
        for (int p = 0; p < 720 * 1280; p++)
        {
            U = (x[p * 4 + 0]);

            Y = (x[p * 4 + 1]);
            V = (x[p * 4 + 2]);
            Y2 = (x[p * 4 + 3]);

           // int one = V << 16 | Y << 8 | U;
           // int two = V << 16 | Y2 << 8 | U;
            int one = Y2 << 24 | V << 16 | Y << 8 | U;
           // mainint[p * 2 + 0] = one;
           // mainint[p * 2 + 1] = two;
            mainint[p] = one;

        }

        m_FPS = UNIT / 20;
        m_b = 211;
        m_g = 197;
    }
```

This function takes that same array of integers and packs it into the GSSF stream pointer

```
        override unsafe public int GetImage(int iFrameNumber, IntPtr ip, int iSize, out int iRead)
    {
        int hr = 0;

        if (iFrameNumber>-1)
        {
            if (iFrameNumber < MAXFRAMES)
            {
                ImageFromPixels_(20, mainbyte);

                m_g += 3;
                m_b += 7;
                int* bp = (int*)ip.ToPointer();
                Random k = new Random();

                StreamReader s = new StreamReader("jpegFile.txt");
                for (int f = 0; f < HEIGHT; f++)
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < (WIDTH); x += 1)
                    {
                        *(bp + (f * WIDTH) + x) = mainint[f * 1280 + x];
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                hr = 1; // End of stream
            }
        }

        iRead = iSize;

        return hr;
    }
```

This sets up the bitmap compression for the output pin of the GSSF
I think i may be doing something wrong here but it looks correct.

```
        override public void SetMediaType(IGenericSampleConfig psc)
    {
        BitmapInfoHeader bmi = new BitmapInfoHeader();

        // Build a BitmapInfo struct using the parms from the file
        bmi.Size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(BitmapInfoHeader));
        bmi.Width = WIDTH;
        bmi.Height = HEIGHT * -1;
        bmi.Planes = 1;
        bmi.BitCount = BPP;
        bmi.Compression = 0x59565955; //UYVY
        bmi.ImageSize = (bmi.BitCount / 8) * bmi.Width * bmi.Height;
        bmi.XPelsPerMeter = 0;
        bmi.YPelsPerMeter = 0;
        bmi.ClrUsed = 0;
        bmi.ClrImportant = 0;

        int hr = psc.SetMediaTypeFromBitmap(bmi, m_FPS);
        DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
    }
```

**UPDATE**
changed it abit

```
        override unsafe public int GetImage(int iFrameNumber, IntPtr ip, int iSize, out int iRead)
    {
        int hr = 0;

        if (iFrameNumber>-1)
        {
            if (iFrameNumber < MAXFRAMES)
            {
                ImageFromPixels_(20, mainbyte);

                m_g += 3;
                m_b += 7;
                int* bp = (int*)ip.ToPointer();
                Random k = new Random();
                StreamReader s = new StreamReader("jpegFile.txt");
                for (int f = 0; f < 720; f++)
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < (1280); x += 1)
                    {
                        *(bp + (f * 1280) + x) = mainint[f * 1280 + x];
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                hr = 1; // End of stream
            }
        }
```

//
            override public void SetMediaType(IGenericSampleConfig psc)
        {
            BitmapInfoHeader bmi = new BitmapInfoHeader();

```
        // Build a BitmapInfo struct using the parms from the file
        bmi.Size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(BitmapInfoHeader));
        bmi.Width = WIDTH;
        bmi.Height = HEIGHT * -1;
        bmi.Planes = 1;
        bmi.BitCount = BPP;
        bmi.Compression = 0x59565955;
        bmi.ImageSize = (bmi.BitCount / 8) * bmi.Width * bmi.Height;
        bmi.XPelsPerMeter = 0;
        bmi.YPelsPerMeter = 0;
        bmi.ClrUsed = 0;
        bmi.ClrImportant = 0;

        int hr = psc.SetMediaTypeFromBitmap(bmi, m_FPS);
        DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
    }
```

//

```
        unsafe public void ImageFromPixels_(long FPS, byte[] x)
    {

        long fff = 720 * 1280 * 3;
        mainptr = new IntPtr(fff);
        for (int p = 0; p < 720 * 640; p++)
        {
            U = (x[ p * 4 + 0]);

            Y = (x[p * 4 + 1]);
            V = (x[p * 4 + 2]);
            Y2 = (x[p * 4 + 3]);

            int one = Y2 << 24 | V << 16 | Y << 8 | U;
            //int one = V << 16 | Y << 8 | U;
            //int two = V << 16 | Y2 << 8 | U;
            //mainint[p * 2 + 0] = one;
            //mainint[p * 2 + 1] = two;
            mainint[p] = one;

        }

        m_FPS = UNIT / FPS;
        m_b = 211;
        m_g = 197;
    }
```

[image]

if i change the other numbers within GetImage to alter the height of the video, or if i chnge it inside of ImagePixel then i just get black screens :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointer math sucks. Changed my code from

```
for (int f = 0; f < 720; f++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < (1280); x += 1)
    {
        *(bp + (f * 1280) + x) = mainbyte[f * 1280 + x];
    }
}
```

to

```
Marshal.Copy(mainbyte, 0, ip, 1280*720);
```

and changed BPP from 32 to 16 and it now works without a hitch.

<_<

Answer (score 0):

How comes your loop is up to (720 * 1280), that is one iteration for every pixel in the picture, but within the loop you're doing Y and Y2. It does not look right.

Comment: thats true. ill give that a look

Comment: What you are doing in ImageFromPixels (updated too) does not make sense to me. You are reading 4 byte macropixels by bytes, then you merge them back together in basically the same order and put it back... so basically you just copy data without changing it, in a weird way.

Comment: i take info from a byte[] array and stick it into an int[] array